# How can I send messages to my private telegram channel with Telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I want to send a message to a private telegram channel using python with Telethon.

What I tried:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import Channel

client = TelegramClient('fx', api id, "API hash")
client.start()


def sendMSG(channel, msg):
    entity = client.get_entity(channel)
    client.send_message(entity = entity,message=msg)


sendMSG("Channel Name", "Hello")
```

But this code gives me this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.get_entity' was never awaited
  sendMSG("Channel", "Hello")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telethon is an asynchronous library. This means you need to await almost everything.

```py
import asyncio

async def sendMSG(channel, msg):
    entity = client.get_entity(channel)
    await client.send_message(entity = entity,message=msg)


asyncio.run(sendMSG("Channel Name", "Hello"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works now

Comment: Note that `asyncio.run` sets-up a new event loop. If you create the client outside, you may run into trouble. Either use `client.loop.run_until_complete` instead, or create the client inside.